# Add statistical information to ActiveRecord model relation

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following tables:

**user**

```
id
login
password
```

**milestone**

```
id
expected_date
completion_date
project_id
user_id
```

**project**

```
id
title
description
```

I have already generated ActiveRecord classes User, Milestone, Project. All fields in these classes are exactly the same as attributes in corresponding DB tables.

I need to display a list of projects assigned the specified user. It has to look like this:

```
ID | Title | Amount of milestones | Amount of completed milestones
```

Now I'm retrieving projects like this:

```
$projects = Yii::$app->user->identity->getAssignedProjects()->all();
```

Where `getAssignedProjects()` method looks like this:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

...

public function getAssignedProjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Project::className(), ['id' => 'project_id'])->via('milestones');
}

}
```

This methods returns me all projects assigned to the user. But, however, these models don't have an amount of milestones and amount of completed milestones.

I can retrieve all needed information with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    proj.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.*,
        COUNT(m.completion_date) AS completed,
        COUNT(1) AS total
    FROM project AS t
    LEFT JOIN milestone AS m ON m.project_id = t.id
    GROUP BY t.id
) AS proj
INNER JOIN milestone AS ms ON ms.project_id = proj.id
WHERE ms.user_id = 1
GROUP BY proj.id;
```

But I cannot find a way to implement it in terms of ActiveRecord. Is it possible to add these fields to the Project model or somewhere else? If it is possible, can you show me, please, how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the var for the field you need.

For activerecord Yii2 automatically generate the field retrieving from the table schema. For calculated field like the field used `AS` result for query alias you must add the related var name to the model

```
class yourClass extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

public $your_var_name;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'your_table';
}
```

make sure the var name match exacly the alias used in your query..
Then you can refer to this new field like others in model..

Comment: Yes, I've read something similar in docs or other SO questions. However, I don't understand where to put the code, which is responsible for retrieving statistical information. Is it possible to eager load this information when I call the `Yii::$app->user->identity->getAssignedProjects()->all();` method? And, also, do I have to use QueryBuilder or work with plain SQL?

Comment: The Query builder is the more direct (ans simple) solution. For the User model I don't know if is right accessing  by identity like you have mentioned, but you can  get the value by User model. User:AssignedProject. ..I hope is useful for you.

Comment: I think, I understand what you mean. Thank you. I'll leave this question open for a couple of days. Just in case somebody will be able to suggest something else.